# $2y'' + (x + 1)y' + 3y = 0$ with power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am trying to solve this ODE with power series.

$$2y'' + (x + 1)y' + 3y = 0$$

$$x_0=2$$
since $x_0$ is an ordinary point, the answer we guess is:

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-2)^{n}$$

we get:

$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_n(x-2)^{n-1}$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_n(x-2)^{n-2}$$

replacing in the equation and doing some simplification, here is the recurrence relation that I find:

$$a_{n+2}=-\dfrac{3(n+1)a_{n+1}+(n+3)a_{n}}{2(n+2)(n+1)} $$

(is it true?)

but it seems like there is no general formula for this series, or at least I can not find it.
I wrote the Equation for $n=0,1,2,3$ and it has no pattern.

Can you help me, Please?

Comment: In $y'$, the summation starts with $n=1$ and in $y''$ it starts with $n=2$.

Comment: @markvs yes it's a typo. in my calculations I assumed what you say.

Comment: If you are asking whether the power series would equal to known elementary functions, then the answer is no: I plug your DE into WolframAlpha and the answer is in terms of imaginary error function. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2y%27%27+%2B+%28x+%2B+1%29y%27+%2B+3y+%3D+0+